# Auxiliary verb at the beginning

Tags: sentence-construction, subject-auxiliary-inversion

The auxiliary verb can come at the beginning of a sentence and that wasn't a question like this

> It is quite possible that, had they been born into a life of privilege, they wouldn't have committed their crimes.

or we say they had been born.....

Comment: it's a hypothetical situation which means the same as if they were born into  a life of privilege, they wouldn't have committed their crimes.

Comment: I recently notice your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> **Had** they been born into a life of privilege, they wouldn't have committed their crimes.

is a case of inversion in Type 3 conditionals, being equivalent to:

> **If** they **had** been born into a life of privilege, they wouldn't have committed their crimes.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.